# @ModelAttribute value not available in case of Validation Error

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am pretty new to thymeleaf and not too experienced with Spring. In my controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("form")
@SessionAttributes(types = {Root.class /** another type here**/})
public class FormController extends BaseController {

    @ModelAttribute("errorMap")
    public Map<String,Integer> getErrorMap(Root root, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        Map<String,Integer> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("somevalue",5); // pretend there are 5 errors for somevalue.
        // some logic here processing bindingResult
    }

    @GetMapping
    public void show(@Valid Root root)
        // do nothing here, just show the page
    }

    ...
}


public class BaseController {

    @ExceptionHandler
    void handleBindException( BindException bindException, 
        Model model, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpSession  session) throws Exception {
        model.addAllAttributes(bindException.getModel());
        addModelAttributes(model, request, true, session);
    }

    @ModelAttribute
    public final void addModelAttributes( Model model, HttpServletRequest request,
        boolean isException, HttpSession session) throws Exception {
        if(GET.matches(request.getMethod()) || isException)
            addModelAttributes(model);
        }
    }
}
```

In my form.html there is this part

```
<div th:if="${errorMap['somevalue']}>0" class="error"> <!-- marked line -->
    <sup th:text="${errorMap['somevalue']}" class="error"></sup>
</div>
```

Now if there are no validation errors everything works fine, the `show(...)` method is called and a `5` is displayed. But if there is a validation error however there is an error `org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "errorMap['somevalue']" (template: "form" - line 38, col 8)` caused by `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1012E: Cannot index into a null value` in the marked line.

I expect this to work especially in case of validation errors. What am I doing wrong here or misunderstanding?

Comment: Because you are destroying the model in your `handleBindException` method. Also why on earth that error map in the first place, there are better ways to check if there are errors, use those instead. Basically you are trying to outsmart and work around Spring and the thymeleaf integation

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Most code was written by a colleague. How not to „destroy the model“? The error map is there in order to mark sections of a form, not a single field. All of these model parts are contained in Root. Are there better ways to do this, too?

Answer (score 0):

A simple, dirty quickfix is to add a method which adds the model attribute manually:

```
protected void addErrorAttribute(Model model) {
    Root root = (Root)model.getAttribute("root");
    BindingResult bindingResult = (BindingResult)model.getAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.root");
    model.addAttribute("errorMap", getErrorMap(root, bindingResult));
}
```

and call this method from the `handleBindException(...)` method.